# Roll over on array in Ruby

Tags: ruby, arrays, ruby-2.0

I have an array in Ruby 2.0:

```
arr=[1,2,3,4,5]
```

I would like to be able to do something like:

```
arr[6] #=> 2
```

That is - roll over the end of the array and restart. Is that possible?

Comment: no, but you could patch the `[]()` method of array and make it behave like you want to! i don't think that you should do it...

Comment: It would be better to extend `Array` with an according method instead of overriding an existing method, which may result in unexpected behavior.

Comment: What about `arr[6 % arr.size]`

Comment: Stefan, could you provide an answer? Then I will approve it. It is the best and easiest solution.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This would work:

```
arr = [1,2,3,4,5]
arr[6 % arr.size] #=> 2
```

Answer (score 1):

Yes, it is possible to patch `Array` class in such way:

```
module RollOver
  def [](index)
    super index % size
  end
end

Array.class_eval do
  prepend RollOver
end

array = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5]
puts array[6] # => 2
```

But it is **NOT** recommended. Imagine how much code could be broken because of this patch. You better define another method for such operation.

**UPDATE**

If this behaviour is needed for one particular array only, then the best solution is:

```
array = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5]

def array.[](index)
  super index % size
end

puts array[6] # => 2
```

Yes, Ruby allows that :-)

Comment: I agree - that is not the way (even if it works). I don't need to make it available on all arrays - just one.

Comment: Ah, in this case there is a nice solution. See an update in a minute.

Comment: Ok - Stefan gave this suggestion first, but please see my comment under his answer.